# Как лучше перевести «Hooloсk tianxing»?

Tags: переводы

Как лучше перевести на русский язык название вида обезьян, недавно обнаруженного в Китае? Английский вариант — *Hoolock Skywalker gibbon*.

**UPD**

> со временем термин выберут специалисты

Вообще это не единственный случай, где требуется выбрать русскоязычное название биологического вида, которое формально отсутствует. Возможно, правильнее было бы задать этот вопрос на биологическом форуме. Однако я не могу вписать в перевод статьи английский вариант (Hoolock tianxing или Skywalker hoolock gibbon), а калька (хулук, хулок Скайуокера), возможно, вызовет непонимание у читателей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Хулок" это устоявшийся термин, а не калька (калькой вообще называется что-то почти противоположное Вашему пониманию, посмотрите в словаре значение этого слова). Вы вполне можете вписать в перевод вариант "Hoolock tianxing" (это название в научной классификации) и дать в скобках английский перевод и, при желании, буквальный — "ходящий по небу", а также объяснить этимологию как самого термина, так и английского перевода.

> Вообще это не единственный случай, где требуется выбрать русскоязычное
>   название биологического вида, которое формально отсутствует.

Вы совершенно правы. Более того, имеется сотни тысяч терминов в научной классификации родов и видов и только ничтожный процент этих терминов имеет переводы на национальные языки. Это нормальная ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Английское название в данном случае по смыслу соответствует китайскому 天行 (tian xing или тянь-син), "небесное путешествие" (вероятно, это связано с перемещением гиббона на высоте между деревьями). Созвучие с именем известного в западной поп-культуре персонажа Skywalker (букв. идущий по небу), по-видимому, и привело к закреплению англоязычного названия. В русскоязычной вики-статье не спешат это перенимать - со временем термин выберут специалисты (возможно, это будет просто транскрипция с китайского, хотя нельзя исключить "воздушного" или "летающего" хулока).

Толкование названия в интернет-статьях как "движение небес" может быть связано с ошибочной трактовкой tianxing как 天兴 (небесный подъём/процветание) - такое название использовалось для обозначения некоторых китайских династий; 天星 (небесная звезда) с похожей транскрипцией встречается наряду с 天兴 в китайской топонимике.

Answer (score 0):

**Hoolock tianxing** или **Skywalker hoolock gibbon**.

**Хулоки** (лат. *Hoolock*) — род приматов, обитающих в Юго-Восточной Азии; один из родов подсемейства гиббоновые, которых называют «малыми гоминидами».
Известно 3 вида: Западный хулок (*Hoolock hoolock*), Восточный хулок (*Hoolock leuconedys*) и *Hoolock tianxing.*

Новый вид китайских гиббонов назвали в честь Люка Скайуокера, персонажа фантастической киносаги «Звездные войны».
Исследователи называют его **хулоком Скайуокера** – отчасти потому, что китайское написание названия (Hoolock tianxing) читается как «движение небес», отчасти из любви к «Звездным войнам».

[Хулоки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)
[Новый вид китайских гиббонов](https://www.gazeta.ru/science/news/2017/01/11/n_9546695.shtml?updated)